# WordPress Media as a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, media

I am building a WordPress website that will allow members to upload media such as videos, images, etc. They will do this on a public form at for example: `domain.com/upload`

The form will ask for a Title, a brief summary, show some categories to choose from, and finally a file uploader. The user will then be able to submit the form and it will appear on the site as a post but instead of being just text it is a piece of media.

I have created a custom post type and all seems to be fine, the problem I have is how to deal with the media upload, as the default WP method is to upload an item and then manually insert it into the post (and you can have as many inserted as you like). Where as I want users to be only able to upload one file per post and not have to insert the file into a post because the file itself is the post. They will also be able to upload a featured image.

Any ideas on how I can develop this? Thanks.

Comment: A WordPress media item by default *is* a post, complete with title, excerpt, description etc. - why not just use the built-in post type `attachment`, and reap the rewards of all the associated functions? `(media_handle_upload()`, `wp_get_attachment_url()`, `wp_attachment_is_image()`, the list is endless)

Comment: Sounds interesting. But what about custom taxonomies and comments?

Comment: What about them? Attachments support comments out-of-the-box, and as for custom taxes, just register them as you would normally for the `attachment` object.

Comment: Is their an example of this? I have never seen comments on attachments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just tried adding a custom taxonomy to the attachment but it doesn't show up in the admin anywhere. How would I create new categories etc for them if I can't see them?

Comment: The custom taxonomy, once registered, will appear under whatever post type you've registered it with. For example, if you've registered it with the "post" type, then you'll see the custom taxonomy appear under the "Posts" panel in your Admin sidebar. Unfortunately, at least with 3.1, there's something weird going on with custom taxonomies and attachments - you don't get that nice checkmark meta box, instead it's just a blank text field and you have to manually enter the custom taxonomy name in there. Bit of a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WP upload methods to upload your file to the server. Then (depending on your upload's media type) you would insert HTML representation of the file into the post (e.g. parse a text file, create  tag for image or embed a video).

If you want to see some working example, please let me know. I just outline the flow:

- `wp-handle_upload()` to physically upload a file
- `wp_update_post()` or `wp_insert_post()` depending on whether you're creating a new user post or editing existing one. Both methods require one argument - Post object. That's where you put your content (as a post_content field of course) and post data