# Allow users to upload a video in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, video, plugins, media

How could you allow users to upload a video in their profile and display it on wordpress? Does anyone know of a plugin?

**"Does anyone know of a plugin? in regards to the first question and topic"**

very **similar to** this post:

[WordPress Media as a Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380037/wordpress-media-as-a-custom-post-type)

**Dated 2010..** which is why I started a new post.. alot has changed..

I have set up a login so far with **WP User Manager** and need to allow a **user** to upload a video link or video so that the video is displayed on their profile.

Using  **Advanced Custom Fields PRO** to make it frontend.

documentation:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is outside the scope of this site. Questions should be programming-related, and questions asking for recommendations or suggestions are discouraged. For future reference, please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here. 
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: **"Does anyone know of a plugin? in regards to the first question and topic"** 

very **similar to** this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380037/wordpress-media-as-a-custom-post-type

**Dated 2010..** which is why I started a new post.. alot has changed..

I have set up a login so far with **WP User Manager** and need to allow a **user** to upload a video link or video so that the video is displayed on their profile.

Using  **Advanced Custom Fields PRO** to make it frontend.

documentation:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress there is a plugin called User Frontend Pro. This allows for you to create a frontend login for a user as well as it will give you the ability to create a custom frontend form. I used Advanced Custom Fields to create custom form fields for the data entered into this form. I was then able to make a custom post with CPT UI and create a single.php for the template of the post being created by a frontend user. This form allowed for the video with a Custom field to be entered as well as other types of information. There is a certain amount of coding you need to understand in php in creating the template structure, but the list of plugins in wordpress that will allow this to made rather simple are: ACF, CPT UI, and Frontend User Pro.